# AngularJS dynamically add ngclick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Am trying to add ng-click dynamically I know how it can be done in Jquery but don't know how I would do this in AngularJs. My code plots series of dots on a canvas and I want each dot to be clickable, am not sure how this can be done in Angular.

AngularJS Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

$scope.data = [
          [21,50],
          [30,150],
          [45,75],
          [98,121],
          [67,78],
          [35,80]
       ];

$scope.addData = function() {
     for(i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++){    
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc($scope.data[i][0], $scope.data[i][1], 10, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = "#ccddff";
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeStyle = "#666666";
        context.stroke(); 
      }    
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px gray solid; float: left;> width:500px; height:500px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: You are trying to add click event on a canvas arc object? If that's the case then, you can write the `ng-click` event on the canvas DOM element and because the canvas is static element, it should not be difficult to do this. See this for further details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133825/add-click-event-to-canvas-or-make-area-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't generate view parts from AngularJS controller.
You should only generate data, which could be included in your HTML by for example ng-repeat directive, and then create a custom directive to process data.

Generated HTML could be like that:

```
<my-graph>
  <my-plot ng-repeat="MyPlotCollectionInMyController" />
</my-graph>
```

Then create a custom directive to process "my-plot" or "my-graph" elements.
[Official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Very good explanation and examples [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals).

The principle of a custom directive is to process attributes or in your case HTML elements, to change something : you could enumerate their children, completely replace the element "my-graph" with completely different HTML.

It is not so easy to create a custom directive. And as soon as you want to include a "ng-click", which is another directive, you must manage priorities accordingly : the "ng-click" directive have to be executed after your custom directive.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you reasoning is right BUT anyway ...
I believe you want to use the $compile service