# how to implement print function in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement print function based on the layout I created below.

```html
<html>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

  <script>
    function draw_bordered_rect(context, x, y, w, h) {
var colors = ['grey','red','black','green','orange','purple','yellow'];      
context.rect(x, y, w, h);
      context.fillStyle = "green";
      context.fill();

      context.lineWidth = 3;
      context.strokeStyle = "lightblue";
      context.stroke();
canvasContext.font = '25pt Arial';
      canvasContext.textAlign = 'center';
canvasContext.fillStyle = colors[x];
  //canvasContext.fillStyle = "black";
    canvasContext.fillText('ACTIVITY 1',canvas.width/2-2, 56);
       
    }



    window.onload = function() {
      canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
      canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
      canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

   
base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = 'http://jacobian.xyz/draw/pic1.png';
        base_image.onload = function(){
            canvasContext.drawImage(base_image, 250, 80);
        }

bases_image = new Image();
        bases_image.src = 'http://jacobian.xyz/draw/e.png';
        bases_image.onload = function(){
            canvasContext.drawImage(bases_image, 20, 400);
        }

bases1_image = new Image();
        bases1_image.src = 'http://jacobian.xyz/draw/f.png';
        bases1_image.onload = function(){
            canvasContext.drawImage(bases1_image, 250, 550);
        }

bases2_image = new Image();
        bases2_image.src = 'http://jacobian.xyz/draw/g.png';
        bases2_image.onload = function(){
            canvasContext.drawImage(bases2_image, 450, 545);
        }

bases3_image = new Image();
        bases3_image.src = 'http://jacobian.xyz/draw/h.png';
        bases3_image.onload = function(){
            canvasContext.drawImage(bases3_image, 350, 545);
        }


      draw_bordered_rect(canvasContext, 0, 0, 790, 70);
      draw_bordered_rect(canvasContext, 0, 540, 790, 70);
    
   

canvasContext.fillStyle = 'grey';
 canvasContext.fillRect(20, 150, 40, 40);
canvasContext.fillStyle = 'orange';
 canvasContext.fillRect(20, 200, 40, 40);
canvasContext.fillStyle = 'purple';
 canvasContext.fillRect(20, 250, 40, 40);
canvasContext.fillStyle = 'magenta';
 canvasContext.fillRect(20, 300, 40, 40);

     

canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
 canvasContext.fillRect(70, 150, 40, 40);
canvasContext.fillStyle = 'green';
 canvasContext.fillRect(70, 200, 40, 40);
canvasContext.fillStyle = 'blue';
 canvasContext.fillRect(70, 250, 40, 40);
canvasContext.fillStyle = 'yellow';
 canvasContext.fillRect(70, 250, 40, 40);
canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
 canvasContext.fillRect(70, 300, 40, 40);



    }

  </script>

</html>
```

so that when they click on the print button in the picture then the print dialog would come up.

I think the print function is like this.

```js
function printPage()
{
 window.print();
}
```

any help would be appreciated though.

Comment: You have the correct JS to trigger the print dialog, the trick is attaching click event handlers, and collision detection between the click event and elements **IN** your canvas, have a look at this answer for click position detection http://stackoverflow.com/a/9880302/648350

Comment: What is your question? What didn't work?

Comment: I am having trouble of making the print image clickable in html5. because I want to trigger print function when they click the image.

Comment: Wrong title. Don't ask to implement print function. Search how to implement click on an area on canvas which is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133825/add-click-event-to-canvas-or-make-area-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the buttons not part of the canvas. Have them part of normal html `<a>` or `<button>` tags that you styled.

Then add the the print function to an onclick event on those buttons/links.

That way you can also hide them in your CSS from printing. So they won't show up on the printed end result.